# How to specify the actor in use case for application?

Tags: project-management, actor, use-case

I'm designing a use case diagram for an application and I have a problem with specifying the actor:

Let's say we have a human, he pass a ticket through a CID machine, this CID machine will scan his ticket and trigger the function `void SaveTicketID(string ID)` of the application to save the ticket's ID to the database (notice that the CID machine and the application are two separated systems and my job is to only do with the application)

The question is who is the actor in this case ? The human or the CID machine?

The CID machine directly use the function `void SaveTicketID(string ID)` .
Although the human doesn't directly use that function but without him, the CID machine can't do anything, it can't trigger the function ?

Comment: what is the goal? if the user tap a ticket to open a gate access then the Actor should be `Human` and then the use case should be only one which is `Open Gate`

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would define two actors, human and CID machine, and human would trigger an action in CID, and CID would trigger the function.

If you design a UML diagram from which you want to generate code, this might not be any option because of a wrong syntax (as far as I know, actors can't trigger actor-functions).

BUT: If you design a diagram to speak about the project with other people, then it can be helpful to have all real actors on the plan, and correct syntax is not so important.

Unfortunately, business processes are not part of UML use case diagrams, only software processes. In your case the human passing the machine is a business process step beyond your software.

By the way, you typed the SaveTicketID starting uppercase, but usually functions should start lower case (saveTicketID) to show a clear difference to classes, as most coding guidelines suggest. Of course, that's just a matter of definition.